# Does the pattern of passing in one object instead of many parameters to a constructor have a name?

Tags: java, design-patterns, object-oriented, terminology, naming

If you have a constructor that takes a lot of parameters, like this:

```
  public OrgUnitsHalRepresentation(List<OrgUnitSummaryHalRepresentation> orgUnitSummaryHalRepresentationList,
  int count, int providedCount, int total, int page, int filterLimit, boolean hasNextPage, boolean isDefaultCount)
```

You can use a separate class that takes nothing in the constructor and set these parameters using setters and pass in this into the constructor instead:

```
public OrgUnitsHalRepresentation(Pagination(Name of pattern) p)
```

Does this have a name so that I can use it in my class name?

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6582/on-the-troubles-of-naming-and-terminology

Comment: yes, but the real question is what the pattern is called, if anything. I will add terminology and naming to the keywords.

Comment: @gnat what's your point? it's just a discussion agreeing that questions about naming things are good.

Comment: @AAA see [On discussions and why they don't make good questions](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6742/on-discussions-and-why-they-dont-make-good-questions)

Comment: @gnat you linked a discussion. The conclusion of the discussion was that this is a good question.

Comment: @AAA that's what I read [over there](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6743/31260): "questions that are not answerable — discussions, debates, opinions — should be closed..." And a thorough explanation of why it's so.

Comment: @gnat the first link you shared clearly concludes that "naming" questions like this are good/answerable questions, not discussion questions. You linked it yourself, so I'm not sure why you're trying to contradict it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is the [*Parameter Object*](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ParameterObject) Design Pattern (or [*Argument Object*](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ArgumentObject)), the related Refactoring is called [*Introduce Parameter Object*](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/introduceParameterObject.html).

Answer (score 1):

This seems to me like a normal case of grouping related variables into compact structure, that has been practiced since structures were invented. Considering it is so ancient, I would imagine there is no name for it.

Also, remember one thing : Patterns are much complex than that. Pattern usually means something that introduces SOLID into code. Your case is too simple to be considered pattern. I would simply call it "PaginationParameters"

Comment: I disagree. Anything that is a common solution can be named as a 'pattern'. For example: the Null Object pattern. It's really simple and is considered a pattern.